# Fixed element in window until it's container scrolls out of view

Tags: jquery, css-position, sticky

I'm attempting to fix an element to the bottom of the window however once the elements container begins to scroll up and out of the viewport the element removes itself from it's `position: fixed;` in the window and instead fixes itself to the bottom of it's container.

I have set up a JSFiddle which demonstrates the two scenarios that I am attempting to combine together. Does anyone have any ideas of how i can achieve this?

Comment: It would help if I give you the JSFiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/garyvoss/HFjU6/3437/

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of talking to myself, i managed to figure it out.

Using a nice little plugin called [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) you can trigger an action when an element reaches a certain point on screen.

So when the bottom container scrolled on screen I changed the elements `position: fixed;` to `position: absolute;` which removed it from the bottom of the screen and instead put it at the bottom of it's parent element.

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/garyvoss/rtb5jh4b/) for code